# loop starts from 0 is faster than loop starts from 1?

Tags: c#

look at these 2 loops

```
 const int arrayLength = ...
```

Version 0

```
    public void RunTestFrom0()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < arrayLength; k++)
                    for (int l = 0; l < arrayLength; l++)
                        for (int m = 0; m < arrayLength; m++)
                        {
                            sum += myArray[i][j][k][l][m];
                        }
    }
```

Version 1

```
    public void RunTestFrom1()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < arrayLength; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j < arrayLength; j++)
                for (int k = 1; k < arrayLength; k++)
                    for (int l = 1; l < arrayLength; l++)
                        for (int m = 1; m < arrayLength; m++)
                        {
                            sum += myArray[i][j][k][l][m];
                        }
    }
```

Version 2

```
    public void RunTestFrom2()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i < arrayLength; i++)
            for (int j = 2; j < arrayLength; j++)
                for (int k = 2; k < arrayLength; k++)
                    for (int l = 2; l < arrayLength; l++)
                        for (int m = 2; m < arrayLength; m++)
                        {
                            sum += myArray[i][j][k][l][m];
                        }
    }
```

Results for `arrayLength=50` are (average from multiple sampling compiled X64):

- Version 0: 0.998s (Standard error of the mean 0.001s) total loops: 312500000
- Version 1: 1.449s (Standard error of the mean 0.000s) total loops: 282475249
- Version 2: 0.774s (Standard error of the mean 0.006s) total loops: 254803968
- Version 3: 1.183s (Standard error of the mean 0.001s) total loops: 229345007

if we make `arrayLength=45` then

- Version 0: 0.495s (Standard error of the mean 0.003s) total loops: 184528125
- Version 1: 0.527s (Standard error of the mean 0.001s) total loops: 164916224
- Version 2: 0.752s (Standard error of the mean 0.001s) total loops: 147008443
- Version 3: 0.356s (Standard error of the mean 0.000s) total loops: 130691232

why:

1. loop start from 0 is faster than loop start from 1 though more loops
2. why loop start from 2 behaves weird?

#### Update:

- I did each run 10 times, (that's where standard error of the mean comes from)
- I also switched the order of version tests a couple of time. No big difference.
- The length of `myArray` of each dimension = `arrayLength`, I initialized it in the beginning and the time taken is excluded. The value is 1. So `sum` gives the total loops.
- The complied version is Released mode, and I run it from Outside VS. (Closed VS)

#### Update2:

Now I discard `myArray` completely, `sum++` instead, and added `GC.Collect()`

[image]

```
    public void RunTestConstStartConstEnd()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = constStart; i < constEnd; i++)
            for (int j = constStart; j < constEnd; j++)
                for (int k = constStart; k < constEnd; k++)
                    for (int l = constStart; l < constEnd; l++)
                        for (int m = constStart; m < constEnd; m++)
                        {
                            sum++;
                        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you run it a few times before you start taking values?  The program will always behave sort of erratically the first time it runs.   You need to have the test run a few times and then start collecting data after it runs about 10 times(create an outer for loop to run the test a few times before data collection starts)

Comment: What range of values do you have in the array?

Comment: mmmhhh... how many times did you re-run the experiment?

Comment: @jzworkman yes i did, that's where standard error comes from

Comment: Did you test with `3` as well? How big is the inner array ?

Comment: Try it again with `i < myArray.Length` and `j < myArray[i].Length` etc.

Comment: Your results are all over the place, and keep in mind you are manipulating an array that is enormous (around 300 Mo from my calculation). What you are measuring is the speed the OS is fetching the corresponding int in memory. There are so many factors here it's difficult to say anything meaningful.

Comment: Could we blame cache aliasing for this?

Comment: I completely revised and believe I have your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

This appears to me to be a result of an unsuccessful attempt at optimization by the **jitter**, not the compiler. In short, if the **jitter** can determine the lower bound is a constant it will do something different which turns out to actually be slower. The basis for my conclusions takes some proving, so bear with me. Or go read something else if you're not interested!

I concluded this after testing four different ways to set the lower bound of the loop:

1. Hard coded in each level, as in colinfang's question
2. Use a local variable, assigned dynamically through a command line argument
3. Use a local variable but assign it a constant value
4. Use a local variable and assign it a constant value, but first pass the value through a goofy sausage-grinding identity function. This confuses the jitter enough to prevent it from applying its constant-value "optimization".

The compiled *intermediate language* for all four versions of the looping section is almost identical. The only difference is that in version 1 the lower bound is loaded with the command `ldc.i4.#`, where `#` is 0, 1, 2, or 3. That stands for load constant. (See [**ldc.i4 opcode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldc_i4.aspx)). In all other versions, the lower bound is loaded with `ldloc`. This is true even in case 3, where the compiler could infer that `lowerBound` is really a constant.

The resulting performance is not constant. Version 1 (explicit constant) is slower than version 2 (run-time argument) along similar lines as found by the OP. What is very interesting is that version 3 is **also** slower, with comparable times to version 1. So even though the IL treats the lower bound as a variable, the jitter appears to have figured out that the value never changes, and substitutes a constant as in version 1, with the corresponding performance reduction. In version 4 the jitter can't infer what I know -- that `Confuser` is actually an identity function -- and so it leaves the variable as a variable. The resulting performance is the same as the command line argument version (2).

My theory on the cause of the performance difference: The jitter is aware and makes use of the fine details of actual processor architecture. When it decides to use a constant other than `0`, it has to actually go fetch that literal value from some storage which is not in the L2 cache. When it is fetching a frequently used local variable it instead reads its value from the L2 cache, which is insanely fast. Normally it doesn't make sense to be taking up room in the precious cache with something as dumb as a known literal integer value. In this case we care more about read time than storage, though, so it has an undesired impact on performance.

Here is the full code for the version 2 (command line arg):

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<double> testResults = new List<double>();
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        int upperBound = int.Parse(args[0]) + 1;
        int tests = int.Parse(args[1]);
        int lowerBound = int.Parse(args[2]);   // THIS LINE CHANGES
        int sum = 0;

        for (int iTest = 0; iTest < tests; iTest++) {
            sum = 0;
            GC.Collect();
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int lvl1 = lowerBound; lvl1 < upperBound; lvl1++)
                for (int lvl2 = lowerBound; lvl2 < upperBound; lvl2++)
                    for (int lvl3 = lowerBound; lvl3 < upperBound; lvl3++)
                        for (int lvl4 = lowerBound; lvl4 < upperBound; lvl4++)
                            for (int lvl5 = lowerBound; lvl5 < upperBound; lvl5++)
                                sum++;
            sw.Stop();
            testResults.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        }

        double avg = testResults.Average();
        double stdev = testResults.StdDev();
        string fmt = "{0,13} {1,13} {2,13} {3,13}"; string bar = new string('-', 13);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(fmt, "Iterations", "Average (ms)", "Std Dev (ms)", "Per It. (ns)");
        Console.WriteLine(fmt, bar, bar, bar, bar);
        Console.WriteLine(fmt, sum, avg.ToString("F3"), stdev.ToString("F3"),
                          ((avg * 1000000) / (double)sum).ToString("F3"));
    }
}

public static class Ext {
    public static double StdDev(this IEnumerable<double> vals) {
        double result = 0;
        int cnt = vals.Count();
        if (cnt > 1) {
            double avg = vals.Average();
            double sum = vals.Sum(d => Math.Pow(d - avg, 2));
            result = Math.Sqrt((sum) / (cnt - 1));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

For version 1: same as above except remove `lowerBound` declaration and replace all `lowerBound` instances with literal `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3` (compiled and executed separately).

For version 3: same as above except replace lowerBound declaration with

```
        int lowerBound = 0; // or 1, 2, or 3
```

For version 4: same as above except replace lowerBound declaration with

```
        int lowerBound = Ext.Confuser<int>(0); // or 1, 2, or 3
```

Where `Confuser` is:

```
public static T Confuser<T>(T d) {
    decimal d1 = (decimal)Convert.ChangeType(d, typeof(decimal));
    List<decimal> L = new List<decimal>() { d1, d1 };
    decimal d2 = L.Average();
    if (d1 - d2 < 0.1m) {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(d2, typeof(T));
    } else {
        // This will never actually happen :)
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(0, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Results (50 iterations of each test, in 5 batches of 10):

```
1: Lower bound hard-coded in all loops: 
 Program    Iterations  Average (ms)  Std Dev (ms)  Per It. (ns)
-------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
 Looper0     345025251       267.813         1.776         0.776
 Looper1     312500000       344.596         0.597         1.103
 Looper2     282475249       311.951         0.803         1.104
 Looper3     254803968       282.710         2.042         1.109

2: Lower bound supplied at command line: 
 Program    Iterations  Average (ms)  Std Dev (ms)  Per It. (ns)
-------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
  Looper     345025251       269.317         0.853         0.781
  Looper     312500000       244.946         1.434         0.784
  Looper     282475249       222.029         0.919         0.786
  Looper     254803968       201.238         1.158         0.790

3: Lower bound hard-coded but copied to local variable: 
 Program    Iterations  Average (ms)  Std Dev (ms)  Per It. (ns)
-------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
LooperX0     345025251       267.496         1.055         0.775
LooperX1     312500000       345.614         1.633         1.106
LooperX2     282475249       311.868         0.441         1.104
LooperX3     254803968       281.983         0.681         1.107

4: Lower bound hard-coded but ground through Confuser: 
 Program    Iterations  Average (ms)  Std Dev (ms)  Per It. (ns)
-------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
LooperZ0     345025251       266.203         0.489         0.772
LooperZ1     312500000       241.689         0.571         0.774
LooperZ2     282475249       219.533         1.205         0.777
LooperZ3     254803968       198.308         0.416         0.778
```

---

That is an enourmous array. For all practical purposes you are testing how long it takes your operating system to fetch the values of each element from memory, not to compare whether `j`, `k`, etc are less than `arrayLength`, to increment the counters, and increment your sum. The latency to fetch those values has little to do with the runtime or jitter per se and a lot to do with whatever else happens to be running on your system as a whole and the current compression and organization of the heap.

In addition, because your array is taking up so much room and being accessed frequently it's quite possible that garbage collection is running during *some* of your test iterations, which would completely inflate the apparent CPU time.

Try doing your test without the array lookup -- just add 1 (`sum++`) and then see what happens. To be even more thorough, call `GC.Collect()` just before each test to avoid a collection during the loop.

Comment: Tests redo according to ur advice.

Comment: I like your new benchtest a lot, but the original had an element yours does not: the initial values of the iteration variable were **compile time constants**, possibly allowing for potential compiler optimization. I think that was precisely the point of the testings in the first place.

Comment: @Falanwe: yes, u r correct. My range is const in the initial setup. I updated a test with variable range, which yields similar results as jmh_gr's

Comment: @Falanwe **Excellent** point. I'm redoing some tests where the lower bound is hard coded...

Answer (score 1):

I think Version 0 is faster because the compiler generates a special code without range checking in that case. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms973858.aspx (section **Range Check Elimination**)

Answer (score 0):

Just an Idea :

Maybe there are bitshifting optimizations in the loops so it will take longer when beginning in an uneven count.

I also don't know if your processor might be an indicator for the different results

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, *perhaps* there's a compiler optimization for 0 -> length.  Check your build settings (release vs debug).

Beyond that, unless it's just an issue of your computer doing other work that is influencing the benchmarks, I'm not sure.  Perhaps you should alter your benchmark to run each test multiple times and average the results.